# Initial pickup feels decreased with improper thumping in my royal enfield classic 350 2015 UCE

Tags: motorcycle, power-loss, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

It feels like Low initial pick in my royal enfield  classic 350 UCE since last 5k to 6k kilometres.
Ran- 16000+ kms. 
Recently changed air filter and aslo carburettor  cleaned with spray but not much performance increment feels.
Tyre pressure also checked(40-40).

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. I think you are talking about the Royal Enfield 350 UCE, so I added tags. Please take a minute to use the [edit] feature to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: For a classic 350, please check recommended tyre pressure in owner's manual. It's definitely NOT 40-40. 
As far as the acceleration (pick-up) is concerned, check carburetor diaphragm and clutch-plates. Typically, 16k kms isn't an age for these to wear out, but it also depends on your riding style and the parts used. Royal Enfield isn't known for their quality either.

Comment: @Ghost got solution, actually my bike was running on single spark plug rather than twinspark. Plug cap was removed automatically or by mistake while servicing.