# Loss of power in my royal enfield classic 350

Tags: power-loss

It feels like less power in initial pickup i.e 1st gear and even in 2nd, 3rd gear.
Replaced air filter. Even carburettor cleaned. Oil changed recently.

Comment: This question is almost identical to this previous question you asked. It has the same problems. Increasing the quality of the question will increase the amount and quality of answers. http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/initial-pickup-feels-decreased-with-improper-thumping-in-my-royal-enfield-classi?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial pickup feels decreased with improper thumping in my royal enfield classic 350 2015 UCE](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/initial-pickup-feels-decreased-with-improper-thumping-in-my-royal-enfield-classi)

Comment: What kind of power loss are you experiencing? I'm guessing this is just your perceived amount of power from riding it around. Have you lost five percent? Fifty percent?

Comment: @raydowe 25% to 30%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say, as there isn't much info to go on. A few things to check:

1) Check the spark plugs to ensure you're getting a good spark. Replacing them could help.

2) Make sure you're using fresh fuel. If you have a fuel filter, try replacing it with a new one. Has the bike been sitting unused for any length of time? Bad fuel or fuel that has been sitting can clog up the small passages in your carburetors causing fueling issues.

3) Check the air filter isn't overly dirty, and replacing it or cleaning it if possible.

4) If none of the above issues fix the problem, I'd start checking compression on each cylinder and make sure it's within the spec listed in the service manual.

Comment: Fuel injectors? the 350 has a carburettor (only the 500 had EFI) perhaps you meant jets.

Comment: To be honest I didn't check. I just assumed even a retro style 2015 bike would be FI. You're right, looks like it's carbed.